# How to use component's joomla.asset.json file in module?

Tags: custom-module, web-asset-manager

I have a module in which I would like to add a stylesheet and a script. I am creating a lot of modules for this project, and I would like to use a centralized json file for my scripts and styles, since a lot of them are used here and there.

```
$wa = Factory::getDocument()->getWebAssetManager();
$wr = $wa->getRegistry();
$wr->addRegistryFile(JPATH_SITE.'/media/com_foo/joomla.asset.json');
$wa->useStyle('com_foo.foo');
$wa->useScript('com_foo.fooscript');
```

My current code throws the following:

```
There is no "com_foo.foo" asset of a "style" type in the registry.
```

Shouldn't this be possible? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a relative path in your call to addRegistryFile, ie:

```
$wr->addRegistryFile('media/com_foo/joomla.asset.json');
```

Comment: There is also the shorthand `addExtensionRegistryFile()` method where you can pass just the component name, i.e. `$wr->addExtensionRegistryFile('com_foo');`.

Comment: Thanks to both, that is great!